# How to avoid AutoCAD DWG file being renamed and recreated during save?

Tags: filesystems, onedrive, autocad, virtualfilesystem, virtual-drive

I edit DWG files on my virtual drive, created with Cloud Filter API. When I edit DWG file using AutoCAD, the file is being renamed and than recreated. Here is the sequence of operations in file system when I save a file in AutoCAD:
[image]

I tried several types of hydration policies (Full, Progressive and Partial) and some hydration policy modifiers (DehydrationAllowed, ValidationRequired and None) on sync root, but with no success.

I know that it is possible to avoid the file recreation, at least it is not recreated with SharePoint/OneDrive. AutoCAD somehow correctly detects OneDrive.

How do I avoid file being recreated during save operation?

Comment: The mentioned sequence of operation seems to be missing here...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to prevent the rename of the current drawing to a ".bak" file and the creation of a new ".dwg" file when you save a file.
The simple answer is to set the AutoCAD system variable `ISAVEBAK` to 0 as indicated in this web page [ISSAVEBAK System Variable](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-25AF36C1-CA4A-4C1C-8D93-1C4F436C6C25-htm.html).
However, as mentioned on this page, you could lose the drawing file if there were a glitch during the save process.  Yes - it is possible to lose the whole file due to a glitch.
Be aware that this rename / create process is the standard operational process with AutoCAD.   Unless specifically overridden, this happens during each save of every drawing.
Lastly, note that this setting is saved in the registry.  As such, once set, if applies to the save of every drawing from that point forward - unless un-modified via an AutoCAD AutoLisp routine (such as those that run upon starting AutoCAD)